# combine two SearchGroups in SOSL search

Tags: sosl, search

Can I combine two SearchGroup in one SOSL query? I want to search both in Name Fields and in  Phone fields.
Something like

```
FIND {78*} IN (NAME , PHONE) FIELDS RETURNING Contact(id,name,phone)
```

Answer (score -2):

You can try like this:

```
FIND {78*} IN ALL FIELDS 
RETURNING Contact(id,name,phone 
)
```

Refer [WHERE condition](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_sosl_where.htm)

Updated based on comments

Comment: I have custom objects and I don't know the names of the fields. That's why I want to refer to the fields as group

Comment: In this case, just remove WHERE condition and search All fields

Comment: @SantanuBoral your answer and comment has nothing to do with the question.